# How do I configure Dropbox to log to syslog?

Tags: server, dropbox, syslog

Dropbox is currently running well on Ubuntu **server** 10.04. 
How can I setup dropbox to log any sync in syslog or even separate log file?

Answer (score 2):

You can get some kind of logging by listening to .dropbox/iface_socket. Where .dropbox is the default folder of the dropbox daemon (not client). iface_socket is what the client (open source) and the server (closed source) uses to communicate. Note than I talking about the local client (cli, nautilus-plugin, etc) and local server, not the one that is run on the net by Dropbox.

You can find a ruby script to read this socket [here](http://dropboxwiki.com/Ruby_Script_To_Log_Client_Events_In_Linux), but I was not able to check it.

I'm not sure if this will give you the info that you want, but this is the best that I can think of short of making a feature request to the dropbox developers.

Comment: Capturing data from socket will not do the trick, because service data being transferred continuously, without actual syncing.

Comment: Looks like someone made a Ruby script that does more or less does what you're looking for using iface_socket: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/urekat/20081124/1227498262

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160221145747/http://d.hatena.ne.jp/urekat/20081124/1227498262 as the blog is down. The code still works well on 20.04 LTS + Ruby 2.7.0!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for an alternative to show the dropbox log files. I know it's not the same, but I believe it can be useful for troubleshooting.  Using the script provided by the dropbox, you can create a script starting on your /etc/rc.local redirecting the output to a specific log file with the following command:

```bsh
nohup find $HOME/Dropbox -type f -exec dropbox filestatus -a '{}' \; > /var/log/dropbox.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score -2):

Now I understand the question properly, I think you should be using rsync to do your syncing (and produce proper log files) rather than Dropbox. It's unusual to use dropbox on a server...

Comment: I want dropbox to write in log file.

Comment: I don't think dropbox gives the facility. I think you should really be using rsync, as it's a proper CLI program with the same functionality. (and more)

Comment: I am using rsync wherever it's possible. The question was very clear.